# Group of order $p^nq^m$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a semi-direct product of a finite $p$-group and a finite  $q$-group where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers. We know that $G$ is soluble and every normal minimal of $G$ is elementary abelian. If $G$ does not contain a normal minimal subgroup of order $q^m$ then what we can say about $q$-sylow of $G$? For example, is it cyclic?

Comment: do you mean $p^n q^m$ ?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965046/solvable-group-of-order-pnqm

Comment: It is not clear what order your groups come in the semidirect product. Which is the normal subgroup, the Sylow $p$-subgroup or the Sylow $q$-subgroup? How do you expect anyone to know which you mean???

Comment: In any case, the answer is that you cannot say anything. $G$ could be a direct product, for example.

Comment: Derek Holt: The p-sylow subgroup is normal in G. If q-sylow subgroup of G is a normal subgroup of G then it must contain a normal minimal subgroup of G, So, direct product is not my case.

Comment: The Sylow $q$-subgroup could still be any $q$-group whatsoever. For example, let $Q$ be any $q$-group and let $G$ be a wreath product of a cyclic group of order $p$ with $Q$.